# Azure devops web extension - access token scoped across all organizations

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

In my ADO web extension installed in an organization (say org A), I want to make an API call to update a work item lying in a project in a different organization (say org B). In addition to updating the work item, I also want to fetch some other project details from org B.

I am using the below code in typescript to get the access token

```
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
const token = await SDK.getAccessToken();
```

With the token that I get here, I am able to call any ADO apis for org A https://dev.azure.com/orgA/_apis/projects. But, I am getting a 401 unauthorized error when I am calling the same API for org B.

Am I missing anything here? Do I have to define any scope for getting a token using which I can invoke APIs in any of the ADO organizations I have access to? Or, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [supported scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#scopes) reference document, it seems that there is no such scope covering all organizations. In addition, no arguments are provided in the [getAccessToken()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-sdk/#getaccesstoken--) function to define all organizations.

As workaround , I think you need to use the PAT generated from the UI interface. When generate the token, need choose **All accessible organizations**.

[image]

Comment: This will work. But, it won't be feasible to expect every user to generate a PAT manually to use my web extension. I want some way to get resources from another org accessible by the user without manually creating and handling the expiry of the PATs.

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be achieved at present. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

so I've been able to probably resolve the issue here. There is a setting in "Policy" of the organization. After I turned this on, I was able to access the resources.
[image]